# How to start my asp.net mvc application with the Angular hashbang url?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

When I start my asp.net mvc application (www.mysite.com), the `home` controller `index` action is loaded.

This action serves a view, and in that view my AngularJS app is loaded.

However, my AngularJS app wants to be started at `www.mysite.com/#!/`

**Is there a way to force this, that when you go to the root that it gets redirected to /#!/ ?**

What I have now is this:

```
<system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <!-- this line enables default documents for a directory -->
            <files>
                <clear/>
                <!-- removes the existing default document list -->
                <add value="/#!/"/>

            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
```

but as you can guess this doesn't work.

I tested it at my local IIS and at Azure.

EDIT

To clarify: If I don't put the `/#!/` at the end or the url, Angular does not kick in. Maybe that is the problem, that I do not have my config right?

my home state is this:

```
.state(appConfig.routes.home, {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                'content': { templateUrl: "/Js/views/home/home.html", controller: 'ikvhomecontroller as vmhome' },
                'homeheader@index.home': { templateUrl: "/Js/views/shared/sharedheader.html", controller: 'sharedheadercontroller as vmshhe' }

            }
         })
```

This is my config:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module(Main.config.name, [
        // Angular modules         
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        // Custom modules 

        // 3rd Party Modules
        'ui.router',
        'ngAnimate'
    ])
    .constant('appConfig', Main)
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', 'appConfig', '$httpProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, appConfig, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        console.log('yep, I am at .config');
        if (appConfig.useHtml5Mode)
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        else {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        };
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/', 'index.home');
            $stateProvider
                .state('index', {
                    url: "",
                    views: {
                        "@": { templateUrl: "/Js/views/main.html" },
                        "header@index": { templateUrl: "/Js/views/header.html", controller: "menucontroller as vm" },
                        'content@index': { templateUrl: "/Js/views/content.html" },
                        "footer@index": { templateUrl: "/Js/views/footer.html" }
                    }
                })
                .state(appConfig.routes.home, {
                    url: "/",
                    views: {
                        'content': { templateUrl: "/Js/views/home/home.html", controller: 'homecontroller as vmhome' },
                        'homeheader@index.home': { templateUrl: "/Js/views/shared/sharedheader.html", controller: 'sharedheadercontroller as vmshhe' }

                    }
                });


        }])
    .run([
        '$http',
        '$state',
        '$rootScope',
        '$templateCache',
        function ($http, $state, $rootScope, $templateCache) {
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (evt) {
                console.log(evt);
            });
            $templateCache.removeAll();
        }]);
})();
```

This is the html in the browser:

```
<div id="main" ui-view>
    <div class="imgwrapper"><img src="/Images/iloading.gif" /></div>
</div>


  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/uihelpers/currencykeydown.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/uihelpers/datekeydown.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/uihelpers/labeltitleclick.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/uihelpers/textareagrow.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-locale_nl-nl.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/config.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/App.js"></script>

 <script src="/Scripts/helpers/calcutils.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/helpers/dateutils.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/helpers/SelectHelper.js"></script>
and the rest of my custom code goes here
```

Comment: Why does it start on #!? Please share your angular routes config and the htmls that are served from the server (layout.cshtml and the home/index  view)

Comment: isn't every angular url with the hashbang? (at least all my urls are with a hashbang, like this `xxx.azurewebsites.net/#!/print`

Comment: Can you please upload the files? It will help us answer

Comment: I edited the question and added the state.

Comment: Where do you include the angular script?

Comment: It's loaded after the Angular files, after the config object, and before all the controllers and services

Comment: Show us the html file where the angular.js script is included

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

you should modify your '`route.config.js`' in angularjs like as -

```
angular.module('yourModuleName').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider.

        state('login', {
            url: 'login',
            templateUrl: '/path/to your login page',


        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/', 'login');
    }
]);
```

This will automatically route your page to `localhost/#!/login` when you start your application.

Comment: I have one route like this `state(appConfig.routes.print, {
   url: "/print",` but the url is this `/#!/print`.

Comment: I do not have this part however ` $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/', 'login');`... Is that mandatory?

Comment: @Michel in this,  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/"); is used to send to base url if particular Url not found and $urlRouterProvider.when('/', 'login'); - will redirect to 'login' if base url is hit. So $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/"); should be there atleast.

Comment: I added the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");` part, but it seems the Angular doesn't kick in. I'll post my entire config...